# Finding time needed for a task, given two person's distinct task/time rates

Tags: algebra-precalculus

John can dig constantly at $15$ inches per minute and Linda can dig constantly at $45$ inches per minute. 
A certain hole can be dug by John in $12$ hours.

If hole is dug by John for half the time and both together for the rest of the time, how many minutes does it take to dig the hole?

Comment: Post your attempt please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use data about john to determine the depth of hole: $$\underbrace{\dfrac{15 \;\text{inches}}{\text{minute}}}_{\text{rate of john's digging}} \times \underbrace{\frac{12 \text{ hours}}{1}}_{\text{time needed for john to dig hole}} \times \dfrac{60 \;\text{ min}}{\text{hour}} = \underbrace{15 \times 12 \times 60 \text{ inches}}_{\text{depth of hole}}$$

Let $x$ be the total number of minutes to dig hole needed under the given restrictions.

Then $$\left(\frac 12x\times 15\right) + \left(\dfrac 12 x(15 + 45)\right) = 15 \times 12\times 60$$

Solve for $x$.

$$7.5 x + 7.5 x + 22.5 x = 10800 \iff 37.5 x = 10800 $$ $$\iff x = \dfrac{10800}{37.5}  = 288\;\text{ minutes total time for john and Linda to dig hole}$$

Comment: nice explanation man

Comment: In the 1st line , 12 is hours and 15 & 60 are inches .. Why we multiplying 12 hours with 15 & 60 inches / min ...

Comment: how to implement logic for every problems , i asked generalize question

Comment: Usually, you try to list out all the information you are given, what your aim is, and then look at how the given information relates and try to fill in the gap between what you have, and what you need. For example, we certainly need to know rates of digging, which we have. The fact that it takes john 12 hours to dig the hole was provided for a reason: it is the one piece we need to have, along with john's digging rate, to determine the depth of the hole that needs to be dug. Without knowing that, we have no way to know how long john and linda together need to keep digging.

Comment: Also, approach problems like this with the knowledge that you may have information given in one unit (like hours spent digging), and other information which uses a different related (time?) unit (like minutes). And so we needed to use the fact that there are $60$ minutes in an hour.  Units can really be *helpful* to work with, as a sanity check: units must cancel in a manner that is consistent with the obtaining the correct unit for a calculation: in the first relation above, all the "time-related" units cancel, as desired, since we want "depth" in inches only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9233/discussion-between-ssk-and-amwhy)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  how many inches per minute do they dig together?  In one minute of John digging and one minute of both digging, how many inches are dug?

Comment: 60 inch/min they dig together

Comment: @SSK:  that is the first step.  Does it help?

Comment: 15 Inch / Min (John) + 60 Inch/ min (both ) = 75 Inch / min

Comment: i think we need to find the time

Comment: @SSK:  Now how many of those does it take to get done?

Answer (score 0):

Let the total time taken be $2x $ minute.

Then we have $x\times15+x\times (15+45)=15\times 12\times 60$

$15x$ implies the depth Jhon has dug for first half at a rate of $15$ inches /minute.

$60x$ implies the depth Jhon & Linda has dug for next half at a rate of $15$ inches /minute and $45$ inches /minute.

$15\times 12\times 60$ implies the total depth of the hole which is $12\times 60$ minutes for jhon(at his rate of $15$ inches)

Now solve for $x$ .Remember that total time is 2 times $x$ and not just $x$.

Comment: Is it clear @SSK ????

Comment: yeah some what clear